# Get large window preview back in ubuntu 18

Tags: unity, gnome, 18.04, gui

In **Ubuntu 16** when you had say **10 terminals** and you'd **click them in the task bar**, **you would get a preview** like the one we get in 18 with the super key except only with the windows of that application. **How do I get that in 18?** Having to look through 15 Terminals without that preview kind of breaks the workflow ;)

Comment: Umm... run all the Terminals in one specific workspace (and nothing else)?

Comment: Thats a good idea :) (and also what I am doing rn, kinda hoping for an alternative though)

Comment: What happens if you just click the Terminal icon in the dock? Doesn't that show previews of running Terminal windows?

Comment: It does - but the preview is the super small window preview that is only about 4 times the size of a task bar icon

Comment: Have exactly the same problem, seems like no solution exists other than installing gnome extension like dash to dock. see: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/07/dash-panel-updated-window-peek-new-options

Comment: Whoops, typed it wrong; it should be dash to panel. I tested and works great. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/